# How to clean Python´s shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, developer-tools

Am starting learning python, when i want erase all the result in shell, I need to close the shell, can I do this with some command or control keyboard?

Comment: If you are referring to the interactive shell in a terminal session you can do `Ctrl+d`

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:
import os

```
def clear():
    name = os.name

    if name == 'nt':  # windows
        os.system('cls')
    else:  # mac and linux
        os.system('clear')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.system('clear')` to talk to the operating system, and ask the system to run the clear command. Of course you have to add `import os` at the beginning.